# How to get the playing video URL on a youtube Player (Android)

Tags: android, youtube

I am working with the youtube api on android. I offer videos to the user so he can play them, but when they finish we all know youtube offers you other related videos. 
So, if my user likes some of the related videos, I'd like him to send me a notification and for that I'd like to spare the "long press on the video" --> copy video url --> paste in an email.

Does anyone know how to access the current playing video on the youtube player?

I don't find anything like that in the apis...

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoID + "?autoplay=1&vq=small");
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Comment: autoplay=1&vq=small any other small to large

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener because you do not know which video is playing now!!

There is override method called it gives you the id of currently playing video id.

You can simply make url with video id

```
@Override
public void onLoaded(String videoId) {
   String url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + mVideoId
}
```

You can you this way.

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
        boolean wasRestored) {
    
    player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new PlayerStateChangeListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() {
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onVideoEnded() {
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onLoading() {
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String mVideoId) {
            String url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + mVideoId
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onError(ErrorReason reason) {
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onAdStarted() {
        }
    });
}
```

I've made sample activity which uses most recent youtube api.

This source handle "**Orientation Problem**", "**Media Volume Problem**", "**Youtube Url Parsing Problem**"

1. This is the sample activity code

   https://gist.github.com/TheFinestArtist/5545437
2. Here is git project for sample app

   https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/SimpleYouTubePlayer
3. I also made sample app you can download

   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thefinestartist.simpleyoutubeplayer

Comment: can this fetch the URL from youtube application itself or only our player? Because I need to fetch the videoID from the youtube application.